# Question about proof of $mG$ is subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is from Victor Shoup's book

---

Let $G$ be an abelian group, and let $m$ be an integer. Then
$mG := \{ma : a \in G\}$ is subgroup of $G$.

Proof. The set $mG$ is non-empty, since $0_G = m0_G \in mG$. For $ma, mb \in mG$, we have $ma + mb = m(a + b) \in mG$, and $−(ma) = m(−a) \in mG$.

---

My question about this is the above proof does not prove that $ma \in G$. Isn't that necessary for $mG$ to be a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: That is guaranteed by the closure property of a group.

Comment: @player3236 - only if m belongs to G. Nowhere is that stated. It's only stated that a belongs to G

Comment: I believe the notation $ma := \underbrace{a + a + \dots + a}_{m\ a\text{'s}}$.

Comment: @player3236 - ok, got it. You can put this as answer & i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP's request, I am extending my comment into answer.

For $m \in \mathbb N$, we indeed write $ma := \underbrace{a+a+\dots+a}_{m \ a\text{'s}}$. However this is usually extended to $m\in\mathbb Z$:

For $m=0$, $ma:=0$, the identity of the group.

For $m<0$, $ma:=-((-m)a)$, where the first negative sign stands for the inverse.

In all these cases, we can see that $ma \in G$ by using the closure property of the group $G$ and induction on $m$. Hence $mG \subseteq G$.